# Organic vs Paid Attribution Model

Tags: predictive-modeling, time-series

I'm wondering if there is literature or studies done on how to model organic attribution from paid user acquisition.

So the context is, on our mobile app, we have paid installs that we purchase and organic installs, but we believe organic installs mostly come from either featuring or referrals from current users. Thus, for every paid user we buy, we actually can attribute some organic installs to that paid user.

My problem then is what this coefficient is. My first instinct is to use a granger like model regressing on the previous values of organic and paid installs with a dummy variable for featuring like this:

$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+ ... + \beta_q y_{t-q} + \gamma_1 x_{t-1} + ... + \gamma_q x_{t-q} +\delta_0 z_t+\varepsilon_t$

where $y_t$ is organic installs, $x_t$ is paid installs, and $z_t$ is just a dummy variable indicating whether the game was featured on date $t$

Is this model valid and what would be the best way to determine the order for this model?

Anyways, would love to hear everyone's thoughts or suggestions if there's a well-defined model for this!

Comment: The basic model seems pretty reasonable to me. When you say, "what would be the best way to determine the order for this model?" Do you mean the order of ARIMA terms, or the lag structure? My gut is telling me that you probably don't have a stationary series, and maybe other issues with your error term too.